# Indesign script to change text in a paragraph

Tags: text, adobe-indesign

There's a particular paragraph in my document and I want to replace its content completely with something else programatically. Is there any function to do this? I need something like this:

app.activeDocument.stories[7].paragraphs[0]. = "blah blah blah";
where  is the function that would allow you to replace the content of the paragraph in question to "blah blah blah." I bet this is possible but am not aware of the functions available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you need to use is "contents".

```js
myParagraph.contents = "Bla bla bla";
```